# Restore device by Time Machine backup of another device

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, time-machine

I have a Time Machine backup for an iMac-500GB **and backup size is 100GB**. Now trying to restore it on a Macbook-250GB and it doesn't work and restore application alerts that there's no enough space for 500GB backup on a 250GB device.

Is it possible to force to restore? or Is it possible to create an backup in iMac-500Gb compatible for Macbook-250GB?

P.S: Macbook has ~230GB free space.

Answer (score 0):

I would install as a new Mac and use Migration Assistant.
From the [Apple support site](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18870?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US):

> 1. Open Migration Assistant, click Continue, then follow the onscreen instructions to transfer info from a Time Machine backup or other disk.
> 2. Select the disk, then select what to transfer.
>
>    - Apps: Select the Applications checkbox.  Incompatible apps or apps with newer versions already installed may not be transferred or may not be usable.
>    - Computer settings: Select the Computer & Network Settings checkbox.
>        Your desktop picture, network settings, and more will be transferred.
> 3. To begin the transfer, click Continue.